# How To Highlight Text in a textBox While Typing in another textBox?

Tags: c#, events, textbox

I'm making a typing windows program that has two text Boxes, 
the first is the Source Text textBox and it is read only,
the other is where the user get to type in the text that is in the source TextBox.

When the user typing a letter in the TypingTextBox, I want that letter to be highlighted in the SourceTextBox..

I tried doing this in a couple of events, but none really worked:

```
SourceTextBox.Select(TypingTextBox.SelectionStart , 1);
```

I even Tried Making my own event, Also didn't work.
The thing is, I won't see the SourceTextBox highlighting unless I click on it.
and As I mentioned, I tried putting the above code in events like:
Mouse-Focus-Leave in the SourceTextBox
and: TextChanged in the TypingTextBox.
All didn't work .. :(

and If I manged to do that, Can I change the Highlight color ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is WinForm, you need to set the HideSelection property on the TextBox to "False". As far as changing the highlight colour, none that I'm aware of.